# What is exact meaning inode lookup time in unix?

Tags: unix, hadoop

Hi I am learning hdfs snapshots.

I found a term on apache website `inode lookup time`.

I am new to this term. Can anyone please tell me what does it exactly mean ?

Comment: http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch12lev1sec6

Comment: Time used for an inode lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the help